# Integrality Conjectures

Tags: number-theory, summation

Here are some interesting conjectures I would like to prove. For all positive integers $a=bc,m,n$ the following expressions are integers:

$$c\sum_{k=1}^{am}k\left\{\frac{kbn}{am}\right\}$$

$$\frac{1}{c}\sum_{k=1}^{bm}k\left\{\frac{kan}{bm}\right\}$$

where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the fractional part operator.

Can anyone prove these?

Comment: I believe I have proof though it is messy and I am tired, so I won't post till later.

Comment: Pleasa do not deface your questions. We would rather not delete good content. Furthermore, it is disrespectful to those who have provided answers.

Comment: @robjohn: My student posted material from my unpublished manuscripts. I have asked that he delete all of the offending posts including this one. He has agreed. If you have moderator privileges to help delete these, please do so.

Answer (score 4):

The statement is not true as long as the following code is valid for small $b,c,m,n$ (arithmetic errors, etc.):

[pastebin c++ code](http://pastebin.com/DJ56RsDj)

It outputs lots of counter-examples for both formulas.

Though your original formula (multiples of $6$) from your deleted question, seems to be true.

First counter example of formula one (according to code) is $(b,c,m,n) = (1,1,2,1)$.  On paper we have:
$$
c\sum_{k=1}^{am}k\left\{\frac{kbn}{am}\right\} = \\
1\cdot \sum_{k=1}^2 (k \cdot \left\{\frac{k}{2}\right\}) = \\
1\cdot \{\frac{1}{2}\} + 2\cdot\{\frac{2}{2}\} = \\
\frac{1}{2}
$$
There's a counterexample, *QED*.